# remove double quotes in array from json response swift

Tags: ios, swift, request, alamofire, nsjsonserialization

I am making a url call with Alamofire to GET data as below.

In first step I convert JSON array to this format

> ["a", "b", "b", "c"]

and its work correctly. The question it is `_price` variable is like this

> ["1233", "1333","3422","2422"]

But i need to remove double quotes from `_price` array 
and eventually `_price` show like this

> [1233, 1333, 3422, 2422]

```
class ChartVC: UIViewController {

    var _year : [String] = []
    var _month : [String] = []
    var _price : [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        getData()

    }

    func getData() {
        AF.request(DOLLAR_CHART).response { (response) in
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            if let items = responseJSON as? [[String: Any]] {
                var years: [String] = []
                var months: [String] = []
                var prices: [String] = []
                for item in items {
                    if let year =  item["year"] as? String  {
                        years.append(year)                            
                    }
                    if let month = item["month"] as? String {
                        months.append(month)
                    }
                    if let price = item["price"] as? String {
                        prices.append(price)
                    }

                }

                self._year = years
                self._month = months
                self._price = prices
                print(self._price)

                // show like this when print that["1233", "1333","3422","2422"]
                // how to show like this [1233, 1333, 3422, 2422]
                }
            } else {
                print("json is not array dictionary")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Declare prices array to be of type Int and convert when appending. Why don't you use an array with a customer struct instead of 3 different arrays and shouldn't one year contain many months (and prices)?

Comment: `print(self._price.compactMap { Int($0) })`

Comment: If you've got a problem with a JSON, **post the JSON**

Answer (score 0):

If You want get Integer value from price.

```
if let price = Int(item["price"] as? String ?? ""){
   prices.append(price)
 }
```

And You should define _price and prices arrays as Array of Int.

```
var _price : [Int] = []
var prices: [Int] = []
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Now should be fine

Comment: i used your answer but there is error at if let line like this : Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'StringProtocol' because only concrete types can conform to protocols

Comment: So You can try cast it to String. Try something like this: Int(item["price"] as? String ?? "")

Comment: I checked it in playground and I've edited my answer